# UIView y calayer

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy aprendiendo acerca de Core Animation, y por lo que entendí acerca de `CALayer` y `UIView` es el `layer` de la `view` se encarga de dibujar la misma ya que usa el gpu y no el cpu, por lo que su rendimiento es mas efectivo. ¿Hasta ahora, entendí bien?

Ahora mi duda, las propiedades de la layer pueden llegar a hacer lo mismo que las propiedades de la vista? Es decir, ¿si yo modifico mi layer estoy modificando mi vista o solo el layer?
Ejemplo: Si uso `view.frame` sería lo mismo que `view.layer.position` y `view.layer.bounds`? (Position sería el punto izquierdo y arriba, y bounds se encargaría de el tamaño)

Answer (score 1):

Un UIView es una envoltura sobre un CALayer, añadiendo el manejo de eventos y los gestures, por ejemplo. Puedes crear un CALayer sin UIView pero no un UIView sin CALayer.

Por lo tanto cuando modificas una propiedad en la vista lo que estas haciendo en realidad es modificar el layer.

Por ejemplo:

```
let view = UIView()

view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50) // Esto es lo mismo que
view.layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50) //que esto

view.alpha = 0 //O esto 
view.layer.opacity = 0 //a esto
```

Eso si, todas las propiedades del layer no están expuestas en el UIView, como por ejemplo el cornerRadius o el anchorPoint.

Si quieres entrar en más profundidad en el bonito mundo de Core Animation te aconsejo este libro:

iOS Core Animation: Advanced Techniques  - [Amazon](https://www.amazon.es/iOS-Core-Animation-Advanced-Techniques-ebook/dp/B00EHJCORC/)